# Determine the new line character in a text file?

Tags: text

given a text, is there a program that can detect what the new line character is, the Windows, Mac, or Linux one?

Eg, the following text is shown by `less`

> memor:^M^Mis storage directly accessible by CPU^M^MThe term "memory"
>   is often (but not always) associated with addressable semiconductor
>   memory, i.e. integrated circuits consisting of silicon-based
>   transistors.^MThe semiconductor memory i s organized into ^Mmemory
>   cells

I thought ^M is the new line character under Mac.
But in emacs, I searched by Ctrl-q Ctrl-m and found nothing.

Thanks.

Comment: `file` command sould give a clue, `dos2unix` might also help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`file` will report on line endings for text files.  If you run `file` on an ASCII Unix/Linux/OSX text file, for example, it will report simply:

```
$ file test.txt
test.txt: ASCII text
```

If, however the file has DOS/Windows line-endings, it will instead report:

```
test.dos: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

Up to OS 9, Macs used CR as the line ending.  When presented with such a file, `file` will report:

```
test.mac: ASCII text, with CR line terminators
```

[With OSX, Macs converted to standard Unix line endings.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)

Comment: If a text file is a mixture of text from Linux, Macs, and Windows. Will `file` still report the right new line character?

Comment: @Tim I tested it on some mixed files and it correctly reported mixed endings. For example, with all three types, it reported  `ASCII text, with CRLF, CR, LF line terminators`.

Comment: I tried this and it gave me `ASCII text, with very long lines`.  The terminators are LF

Comment: @wordsforthewise LF terminators are the unix and linux standard.  If a file has LF terminators, then `file` doesn't mention what terminators are used.  See the first example in the answer above.  Terminators are only mentioned if the file has non-unix terminators.  See the second and third  examples in the answer above.  Separately, it is likely that your file has one or more long lines.

Comment: Yes, I understand.  I just thought it was funny it said 'very long lines'